# Таблица без сдвига строк в Twig

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

Имеем коллекцию товаров `products`. У каждого товара есть несколько цен для разных сайтов `product.prices`. Есть так же коллекция с сайтами `sites`.
Задача: сформировать таблицу, где строка - товар, столбец - сайт. В ячейке - цена, соответствующая каждому сайту.

```
Наименование | Цена сайта 1 | Цена сайта 2 | Цена сайта 3
```

Пробуем вывести таблицу:

```
<table class="table">
    {% for product in products %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
            {% for site in sites %}
                {% for price in product.prices %}
                    {% if price.site == site %}
                        <td>{{ price.price }}</td>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Проблема в том, что у товара не всегда присутствуют цены для каждого из сайтов. И в таких случаях строки сдвигаются влево. Как реализовать таблицу без сдвига строк?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вставлять ячейку в любом случае, есть цена или нет:

```
<table class="table">
    {% for product in products %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
            {% for site in sites %}
            <td>
                {% for price in product.prices %}
                    {{ price.site == site ? price.price : ''}}
                {% endfor %}
            </td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Это было бы слишком просто :) В этом случае, при _каждом_ проходе _каждого_ цикла, когда цена товара сайта отсутствует, добавляется пустая ячейка. Это добавляет лишние пустые ячейки.

Comment: После правки: тоже не сработало. Все равно сдвиг влево сохраняется.

Comment: Я не понял, это же таблица, какой отступ? пустые ячейки должны быть. Покажите ваш сдвиг влево.

Comment: Смутно припоминаю что совсем пустую ячейку нельзя было делать, поставил `&nbsp;`

Comment: Прошу прощения, вправо. Вот что получается при вашем коде http://take.ms/aaqFP &nbsp; не помог

Comment: А, понял структуру, надо 'td' поставить циклом выше